# Render the full Json array in response.body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing

This test keeps failing Im not sure what to do. I am guessing a fix would be to render the raw Json array but I am utterly lost.

## error

NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    /Users/newuser/railschallenge-city-watch/test/api/emergencies_create_test.rb:10:in`block in '

## emergencies controller

```
def create
    @emergency = Emergency.new(emergency_params)
    if @emergency.save
        render  json: @emergency.to_json , :status => 201
    end 

end


test 'POST /emergencies/ simple creation' do
post '/emergencies/', emergency: { code: 'E-99999999', fire_severity: 1,          police_severity: 2, medical_severity: 3 }
json_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

assert_equal 201, response.status
assert_equal nil, body['message']
assert_equal 'E-99999999', json_response['emergency']['code']
assert_equal 1, json_response['emergency']['fire_severity']
assert_equal 2, json_response['emergency']['police_severity']
assert_equal 3, json_response['emergency']['medical_severity']
```

end

Comment: json_response['emergency'] is nil. print the json_response value to debug.

Comment: it's the way the test is written its looking for this: emergency ={code:" E-99999999'", fire_severity = "1 ", police_severity:" 2" , medical_severity = " 3"} literally , but its receiving this: {code:" E-99999999'", fire_severity = "1 ", police_severity:" 2" , medical_severity = " 3"}

I'm trying a way to get the first out put rendered a raw JSON, or at least that is what I'm thinking. I really don't know Ive never messed with JSON before on a legit level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
render json: @emergency.to_json(:root => "emergency"), :status => 201
```

Comment: Thank you , you gave me a great idea I tried that it didn't work but, your thought process totally helped me.

Answer (score -1):

```
render  json: {"emergency" => @emergency}.to_json , :status => 201
```

Comment: This solution is very ugly. :/